# How can I access the ID of the parent object inside a object entension

Tags: hotchocolate

I have a class `User` with a property `Id`. I also have some binary data in my file system for each instance of that class - the names of the files are the `Id` of the object.
I've written a type extension to provide a field with the text content from the files:

```
[ExtendObjectType<User>]
public sealed class UserExtensions
{
    private readonly IStorageReaderWriter readerWriter;

    public UserExtensions(IStorageReaderWriter readerWriter)
        => this.readerWriter = readerWriter;

    public async Task<string?> GetData([Parent] User user, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        => await this.readerWriter.Read($"{user.Id:D}.json", cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

This works fine as long as I query the user with its `Id`:

```
query {
  users{
    id
    data
  }
}
```

In this case, `GetData` gets a `User` instance with the `Id` already set and can look up the file content by this `Id`.

As soon as I omit the `Id` in the query, it's not populated in the User for the `GetData` method. So, this query returns a list with `data = null`, because for each record `User.Id` is null.

```
query {
  users{
    data
  }
}
```

Is there a way to tell hot chocolate that I need the `Id` property, regardless whether the client query requests it or not?

Comment: How does your users resolver look like? I believe the answer is hidden there